# How would I get all public properties of object faster than with PropertyInfo.GetValue()?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have the following generic code that iterates over `IEnumerable<T>` (assuming all objects are exactly of type `T`) and for each item it retrieves all properties values and appends them to a `StringBuilder`:

```
Type t = typeof(T);
var properties = t.GetProperties();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(item, null);
        // feed to StringBuilder
    }
}
```

and btw the `IEnumerable` comes from a non-trivial Linq-To-Sql query.

So I profile my code and find that of all my code 37,3% time is spent in `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader.MoveNext()` and 31,59% time is spent in `RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue()`.

This is why I'd be happy to find another way of retrieving all properties - one that is faster than calling `PropertyInfo.GetValue()`.

How could I achieve that (preferable keeping the code generic)?

Comment: @BartoszKP `GetProperties` already returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy is to cache a delegate that is not attached to any instance of a particular object. This is a little trickier than it sounds.

Jon Skeet's [article](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx) on the topic is good for the general case, however I thought I'd offer a simplified solution for this specific case.

The workhorse is `Delegate.CreateDelegate` which takes a `MethodInfo` and returns a delegate that takes the instance as a parameter. The `MethodInfo` is provided by `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod`. The trick is that we want all the delegates to return an `object` but we can't simply use `Func<T, object>` as the delegate type. That type is not going to be compatible without a boxing instruction for value types.

To do that we leverage a helper method (below it is called `CreateDelegateInternal`) which we will invoke by reflection with the correct run-time types. Since we only call this once when loading the delegates, it is not too costly. Then we will wrap the strongly-typed delegate in a less strongly typed lambda which will insert the correct conversion.

```
public static class ReflectionHelper<T>
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> propertyDelegates = CreateDelegates().ToArray();

    private static IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> CreateDelegates()
    {
        var helper = typeof(ReflectionHelper<T>).GetMethod("CreateDelegateInternal", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var method = helper.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), property.PropertyType);
            yield return (Func<T, object>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { property.GetGetMethod() });                
        }
    }

    private static Func<T, object> CreateDelegateInternal<T, TReturn>(MethodInfo m)
    {
        var f = (Func<T, TReturn>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, TReturn>), m);
        return t => (object)f(t);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, object>> Properties 
    {
        get { return propertyDelegates; }
    }
}
```

and your code would look something like:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach (var property in ReflectionHelper<T>.Properties)
    {
        object value = property(item);
        // feed to StringBuilder
    }
}
```

Obviously, you may want may add some validation (to check the property's `CanRead` property) and error handling. Also, you may want to tuple up the `PropertyInfo` in the output so you could print metadata like names, this is left simple for clarity.